# R: pasting (or combining) a variable amount of rows together as one

Tags: r, parsing, paste

I have a text file I am trying to parse and put the information into a data frame.  In each one of the 'events' there may or may not be some notes with it.  However the notes can span various amounts of rows.  I need to concatenate the notes for each event into one string to store in a column of the data frame.

```
ID: 20470
Version: 1
notes: 


ID: 01040
Version: 2
notes: 
The customer was late.
Project took 20 min. longer than anticipated
Work was successfully completed

ID: 00000
Version: 1
notes: 
Customer was not at home.

ID: 00000
Version: 7
notes: 
Fax at 2:30 pm
Called but no answer
Visit home no answer
Left note on door with call back number
Made a final attempt on 12/5/2013
closed case on 12/10 with nothing resolved
```

So for example for the third event the notes should be one long string: "The customer was late.  Project took 20 min. longer than anticipated Work was successfully completed", which then would be store into the notes columns in the the data frame.

For each event I know how many rows the notes span.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Likely using `split` on something like `cumsum(grepl("^\\s+$", txt))` to break it up by `ID:` block. Then use `paste`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (actually, you would be happier and learn more figuring it out yourself, I was just procrastinating between two tasks):

```
x <- readLines("R/xample.txt")  # you'll probably read it from  a file
ids <- grep("^ID:", x)   # detecting lines starting with ID:
versions <- grep("^Version:", x)
notes <- grep("^notes:", x)
nStart <- notes + 1  # lines where the notes start
nEnd <- c(ids[-1]-1, length(x))  # notes end one line before the next ID: line
ids <- sapply(strsplit(x[ids], ": "), "[[", 2)
versions <- sapply(strsplit(x[versions], ": "), "[[", 2)
notes <- mapply(function(i,j) paste(x[i:j], collapse=" "), nStart, nEnd)
df <- data.frame(ID=ids, ver=versions, note=notes, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

#### dput of data

```
> dput(x)
c("ID: 20470", "Version: 1", "notes: ", "  ", "  ", "ID: 01040", 
"Version: 2", "notes: ", "  The customer was late.", "Project took 20 min. longer than anticipated", 
"Work was successfully completed", "", "ID: 00000", "Version: 1", 
"notes: ", "  Customer was not at home.", "", "ID: 00000", "Version: 7", 
"notes: ", "  Fax at 2:30 pm", "Called but no answer", "Visit home no answer", 
"Left note on door with call back number", "Made a final attempt on 12/5/2013", 
"closed case on 12/10 with nothing resolved ")
```

Comment: thanks for the mapply suggestion for notes... I applied that to my code.  Now just running into problems  with memory.  Reading in 25+ millions lines trying to parse it.  Do you know how to read in chunks at a time.  I have a vector detailing the different chunks...so for example read in there first 75 lines, then parse, then read in the next 57 lines and parse...etc...